# How do I fill columns down after a date range array in Big Query?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a sales promotion table where each observation includes the promo item number that people will order and each component of the item along with the start and end dates for the promotion.

I need to explode the dates out into days per observation so I can join with another sales data set at the day level.

That stated, I put together the below query to explode the days out:

```
SELECT 
PROMO_ITEM_NO
,ITEM_NO
,GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(CAST(promo_details.PROMO_STRT_DT as Date), Cast(promo_details.PROMO_END_DT as Date), INTERVAL 1 DAY) as ord_dt
FROM `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.PROMO_DETAILS` promo_details

where promo_details.CORP_CD = "180"
and PROMO_STAT_CD_UI_DESC <> "Cancelled"
and promo_details.PROMO_STRT_DT > "2018-01-01"
```

This seems to get the days right for each promotion, but the output looks like the below:
[image]

How do I get the PROMO_ITEM_NO and ITEM_NO to fill down?

I've tried:

```
Select * 
FROM (select PROMO_ITEM_NO
,ITEM_NO,
CAST(promo_details.PROMO_STRT_DT as Date) as start_date
,Cast(promo_details.PROMO_END_DT as Date) as end_date
FROM `gcp-sc-demand-plan-analytics.Demand_Planning_Ingestion.PROMO_DETAILS` promo_details) dates
```

But that didn't give me the results I wanted.
inner join UNNEST(GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY(dates.start_date, dates.end_date))

Here is an example of what my table looks like using `python`:

```
import pandas as pd
sample_dict = {'start_date': ["2021-01-01", "2022-01-01", "2023-03-01"],
              'end_date': ["2021-01-31", "2022-01-31", "2023-03-31"],
              'promo_item_no': ["a12345", 'b12345', 'c12345'],
              'cannibalized': [1,0,1]}
sample_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(sample_dict)
sample_df.loc[:, 'start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df.loc[:, 'start_date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
sample_df.loc[:, 'end_date'] = pd.to_datetime(sample_df.loc[:, 'end_date'], format = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

Here is the output I'd like to see:

```
sample_df["dates"] = [
    pd.date_range(start, end)
    for start, end in zip(sample_df["start_date"], sample_df["end_date"])
    ]
sample_df = sample_df.explode('dates')
```

I need to be able to replicate this with BigQ SQL.
sample_df

Comment: Can you share the input table (or at least a minimum reproducible example) and the expected output?

Comment: My apologies.  Example code added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need the `UNNEST` function, did you try it?

You can try the below:

```
# Solution 1
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'] AS ord_dt, '2021-01-31' AS end_date, 'a12345' AS promo_item_no
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'], '2022-01-31', 'b12345'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ['2021-01-01'], '2022-01-31', 'c12345'
)

SELECT promo_item_no, ord_dt FROM sample_data, UNNEST(ord_dt) AS ord_dt;

# Solution 2
WITH sample_data AS (
  SELECT ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02', '2021-01-03'] AS ord_dt, '2021-01-31' AS end_date, 'a12345' AS promo_item_no
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ['2021-01-01', '2021-01-02'], '2022-01-31', 'b12345'
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT ['2021-01-01'], '2022-01-31', 'c12345'
)

SELECT promo_item_no, ord_dt FROM sample_data
CROSS JOIN sample_data.ord_dt
```